# Requirements to get the summoner icon for Nemesis mode

Tags: league-of-legends

In the [release news](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/features/meet-your-nemesis-draft) for Nemesis draft mode, it is mentioned that

> we’ll be sending out a fancy summoner icon to all Nemesis Draft
>   players who play the mode without quitting during champion select or
>   the actual game!

However, I'm not sure if just a single game is enough, or is there a minimum no. of games that should be played? Any other requirements to be aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was about to ask the same question too so I searched it, then bumped into this :

[Nemesis Draft Mode FAQ](https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/204191960-Nemesis-Draft-Mode-FAQ#h2q3)

> We’ll begin distributing the icon within a week of the game mode’s end.

1 game without quitting should be enough.

Comment: But does that mean that if we quitted another game, we won't have the Icon?